# Conditional command execution within piped sequence of commands in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipe, conditional-execution

Sorry for bumpy topic name (feel free to edit if you find more fitting title after looking at problem).
Code sample equals 1000 words, so here we go:

```
if [ "$REGEX" != "" ]; then
        find $TEST_DIR -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*(status|stderr|stdout)-captured$' |                                  
        grep -E $REGEX |
        awk '{print(""$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/-captured$/-expected/' | 
        while read -r line; do mv -f $line; done 
else
        find $TEST_DIR -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*(status|stderr|stdout)-captured$' |
        awk '{print(""$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/-captured$/-expected/' |
        while read -r line; do mv -f $line; done
fi
```

What code does is not all that important, I'd just like to find more elegant way to either use "**grep -E $REGEX**" or not. I thought that conditdonal aliases could do the job just like I'm used to from shell usage, but they does not work inside scripts.

I could put in a condition, but I fear performance impact from multiple evaluations.

Any way to make the code "more elegant"?

Comment: Can you describe the input/output you're looking for a little bit better?

Comment: @CarlNorum Don't think it's necessary, but I shall: first find prints path to files matching name `{status,stderr,stdout)-captured`, then these are further filtered by `grep -E $REGEX`. Awk, sed and read, assemble this example:
`./dir/status-captured` into `mv ./dir/status-captured ./dir/status-expected` that is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use `^` (which always matches: it means "start-of-line", which every line has) if `$REGEX` is unset or blank:

```
find $TEST_DIR -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*(status|stderr|stdout)-captured$' |
grep -E ${REGEX:-^} |
awk '{print(""$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/-captured$/-expected/' |
while read -r line; do mv -f $line; done
```

For that matter, you can combine it into the original `find`:

```
find $TEST_DIR -type f -regextype posix-extended \
     -regex '^.*(status|stderr|stdout)-captured$' \
     -regex ".*${REGEX}.*" |
awk '{print(""$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/-captured$/-expected/' |
while read -r line; do mv -f $line; done
```

and for that matter, you can merge all of the rest of your script into `find` as well:

```
find $TEST_DIR -type f -regextype posix-extended \
     -regex '^.*(status|stderr|stdout)-captured$' \
     -regex ".*${REGEX}.*" \
     -exec bash -c 'file="{}" ; mv -f "$file" "${file%-captured}-expected"' \;
```

Comment: Interestingly, first variant performs best in my test tree.
Thank you for really interesting answers.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is:

```
test -n "$REGEX" && cmd="grep -E $REGEX"
find ... | ${cmd-cat} | awk ...
```

If cmd is defined, it is used in the pipe.  Otherwise, cat is used, performing a no-op.
You can also do:

```
find ... |
if test -n "$REGEX"; then
  grep -E $REGEX
else
  cat
fi |
awk ...
```

with exactly the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly ugly, but general, solution.

```
find $TEST_DIR -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*(status|stderr|stdout)-captured$' \
 | if [ "$REGEX" != "" ]; then
        grep -E $REGEX; \
   else \
        cat; \
   fi \
 | awk '{print(""$1" "$1)}' \
 | sed 's/-captured$/-expected/' \
 | while read -r line; do mv -f $line; done
```